# Workflow for getting Github repository updates

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, github

There are a lot of great open-source projects on github. Most of them come with great sample apps.

Now I go through the following steps to get a repository:

1. Visit a github repository, e.g. https://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile
2. Click `Clone in Mac` to clone the project
3. Open `GitHub app` in Macbook
4. Right-click `AppSales` and select `Show in Finder`
5. Open the `xcodeproj` in Xcode
6. Modify `Bundle identifier` in `...-Info.plist` file
7. Modify `Code Signing Identity` in the target
8. Compile and run

Whenever there is any update in the repository, I open the Github app and discard changes made in step 6 to 7 above, and sync. Then go though step 6 to 8.

By using the Github app, how can I keep the changes made in step 6 to 7 and also get new updates also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a git client and most of the repetitive tasks you are doing now will just ... go away. Tower is a good choice, but you can always use the command line as well:

```
git clone https://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile.git
cd AppSales-Mobile/
open -a XCode AppSales.xcodeproj/
```

Run the project, change files, do whatever. Then when ready to get updates from upstream server just do:

```
git pull (or git fetch, then git merge).
```

Alternatively you could add the files you are changing to your .gitignore file, so that they aren't tracked by Git.